# Youtube API "Views" data and Youtube channel views not identical

Tags: youtube-api

I've made a program that fetches the total views my videos have, but it doesn't seem to be updated in real time.
I just checked via the API
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=%22) + youtubeID + "&key=" + youtubeKey
where it says 53530 and then if I go to the website in the "about" tab, it has updated to 53531 but still the API hasn't updated. Is the API not very reliable or am I missing something?

Comment: I do remember read an answer here on Stack Overflow about the channel/video views; it said that the results are different and the *real* count is shown to the channel's owner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.